# Can anyone explain to me that why `\def` is used together with @ in this cls file

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex

Recently, I have found a CV template class [here](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/tree/master/examples) in GitHub

In the file `awesome-cv.cls`, there are some definitions confuse me, like:

```
% Define writer's name
% Usage: \name{<firstname>}{<lastname>}
% Usage: \firstname{<firstname>}
% Usage: \lastname{<lastname>}
% Usage: \familyname{<familyname>}
\newcommand*{\name}[2]{\def\@firstname{#1}\def\@lastname{#2}}
\newcommand*{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familyname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\def\@familyname{\@lastname}
```

**Can anyone explain to me why @ symbol is used here?**

### updates

I found something in [Minutes in Less Than Hours](http://tutex.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-4/hefferon/hefferon.pdf), which might help.
[image]

Comment: Best way to think of this, is if the original author had used `X` instead of `@` (which would work) would you have asked why `X` was being used? `@` may look different  to other letters to a human but (in a class file) they look the same to latex.

Answer (score 2):

Because are designed as internal macros for some package or document class that the final user should not know/use/rewrite. That is, the final user should/could  use `\firstname` in the `main.tex` but not `\@firstname`, because @ (at) is then a special character (as `&`,`%`, etc.) that cannot be usually used in a control sequence, except whilst you  make `at` a normal letter (`\makeatletter`) and until you do not make `at` other type of special character (`\makeatother`). This is made changing the catcodes (see  [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)). There a lot of examples in this site fixing a package bug or change the default behaviour of some class with `\makeatletter (a lot of code with many @) \makeatother`, although ideally the final user should not see this, even if it is their own patch, because that code  is  best placed hiddenly in some .sty or .cls file.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I want to write my own `cls` file, that might be one reason I'f like to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

In a `sty` or `cls` file, the letter `@` changes (of what is called its `catcode`) and it becomes possible to use it in names of macros. In `\def\@firstname`, `\@firstname` is the name of a macro and it will be defined in the instruction.

Comment: You mean it will be used later in the code of `cls` file, because I do identify their appearance in the code followed.

Comment: Yes, the macro `\@firstname` (which will contain the first name of the writer as said in the comment) is used later in the `cls` file or in an `sty` file loaded by the `cls` file.

Comment: what if I remove all the @ symbols and used `\firstname` in the macros below. Is it OK?thanks

Comment: Actualy, I am still confused about the `catcode` concept.

Comment: The code defines `\firstname` and, when used, `\firstname` will define `\@firstname`. Example: if you use `\firstname{Andrew}`, then `\@firstname` will contain `Andrew` and it will be used by commands latex in the `cls` file, for example by `\makeletterclosing`.

Comment: Here, the change of `catcode` of `@` is only a security. In the normal `.tex` file, you won't be able to use `\@firstname`, because, if you type `\@firstname` in your `tex` file, it will be interpreted as `\@` (a first macro) and then the letters `f`, `i`, `r`, etc. If you really want to use `\@fistname` in the `tex` file using that classe, you would have to write `\makeatletter \@firstname \makeatother`.

Comment: sorry for so many questions, so this is usually the case in writting `sty` and `cls` files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96297/discussion-between-f-pantigny-and-ted930511).